# Streaming API & managed package

Tags: managed-package, streaming-api, pushtopic

There is Pushtopic usage within managed package which doesn't work because of the following error (This error was identified from https://workbench.developerforce.com -> Queries -> Streaming Push Topics)

```
4. Subscription Failure: 403::Subscriber does not have access to the entity in this topic
{
  "channel": "/meta/subscribe", 
  "clientId": "3m44lkwlhtstiq1g4urti47dpqv", 
  "error": "403::Subscriber does not have access to the entity in this topic", 
  "successful": false, 
  "id": "4", 
  "subscription": "/topic/XXXXXXXXX"
}
```

The query is defined correctly - namespace is added to field and sobject names
What can be the problem?

Comment: Sharing rules and profiles?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and by deleting the push topic, and creating it again worked.
The query had managed fields and managed objects, and when uninstalling and installing again the managed package, some how invalidates the push topic referring to its data.

Comment: Lifesaver I tell ya!

Comment: Saved my day :p

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check that the user in the target org has permissions to read the object in question. It could be a profiles thing or it might be a licencing issue.

Check that the user has a licence for the package and has been assigned any pertinent permission sets included in the package. If the package doesn't use permission sets and was installed for the Admin user only then you either need to modify all profiles (which gets messy) or reinstall the package and choose the option that makes it available to all users (this is much easier).

Comment: Strangly but I can query referenced sobject like 'Select ns__field__c from ns__sobj'(=query*) but when I run query 'select Name, query* from PushTopic' it says 'Access Denied: You don't have access to the referenced entity in the query'. Mentioned field and sobj are enabled for profiles.